# ASP.NET MVC Client side time convert from model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model

My cshtml page contains the following code for `DateTime`, which is some server time fetched from sql.

```
<tbody>
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model) 
            {  
                <tr>
                    <td>     
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.someDate)                                          
                    </td>
```

The type of the `someDate` property is `DateTime`. I would like to show the time in respect to client/browser time zone, preferably using JavaSscript. What is the simples way of doing this? I looked at various similar answers but none using `Html.DisplayFor` and JavaScript. I tried to use this code, but it doesn't work:

```
@(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.someDate)).toLocaleString();
```

or

```
var localDateTime = new Date(item.someDate).toLocaleString();
@Html.DisplayFor(localDateTime )
```

The above may require template that I am not comfortable with as it is giving error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this without using JavaScript. Here's something you could try (using jQuery for convenience):

```
foreach (var item in Model) 
{  
   <tr>
       <td data-iso="@item.someDate.ToString("o")"></td>
   </tr>
}
```

Afterwards, in `document.ready` just parse the date and set the locale in the `td`:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("td").each(function (index, elem) {
        var date = new Date($(elem).data("iso"));
        $(elem).html(date.toString());
    });
});
```

This solution converts the date using the ISO 8601 format, which is one of the many formats supported by the JavaScrip Date constructor.

Comment: I tried above and it is not working. The code never enters  $("td").each(function (index, elem)  function. I put debugger; inside it as first statement and browse in chrome with developer tools. Logically it appear correct as I like to use javascript , jquery is ok till solution didn't become complex. but there is some issue in jquery.

Comment: Does the table get generated? Can you see it in your web page? Can you inspect the elements using the developer tools? If the table is correctly rendered, then directly in the console try `var cells = $("td")` and see if all the table cell are selected.

Comment: yes, the table get generated but the date field is empty. i debug and found that the code is not entering in $("td").each(function (index, elem) { function.

Comment: var cells = $("td") is undefined

Comment: Strange, I inspect the cell and found <td data-iso="2015-06-01T09:47:31.7570000">                        
                    </td>

Comment: Where are you placing the JavaScript code? Also, after writing `var cells = $("td")` in the console, write `cells` again, and hit "return". You should see all the available cells.

Comment: Looks I am almost there. yes the table is there and for a particular cell the values are as follows:  outerHTML: "<td data-iso="2015-06-02T14:05:52.9500000"></td>"
outerText: ""
id: ""
innerHTML: "  "
innerText: ""  So innerHTML is blank, that is why cell is blank. Without id , as the table is generated dynamically. how can we set the inner HTML. I did try both below but still innerHTML is empty.
                    $(elem).html(date.toString()); and 
                    $(elem).innerHTML= date.toString();

Comment: @AKS, using `$(elem).html(date.toString());` should work; I updated my answer. Please check each value in the `each` function: `elem` should be a `td` element, `$(elem).data("iso")` should return an ISO 8601 date (e.g. "2015-06-01T09:47:31.7570000") as string, `date` should be a valid JavaScript Date object (corresponding to the ISO date).